# Embedding VLC Stream in Website

Tags: video, stream, streaming, live, vlc

I setup a VLC stream in my computer and successfully tested with another vlc on my computer.
But I want to embed the vlc stream in my webpage.
I tried many solution that I found online.
Nothing worked.
Can anyone give me a real working solution ?

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Install VLC and install Mozilla plug-in or ActiveX control for (FF, IE or Chrome)

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"  width="100%"  height="100%" id="vlc" loop="yes" autoplay="yes" target="http://11.11.11.11:8000/"></embed>
```

Comment: Where can I find the suggested plugin?